# how to get back window.baseUrl from razor code into my external .js file

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have included this javascript function in head section of view page like this, i want to call this window.baseUrl inside my people.js file which resides in scripts folder:

```
   <head>
   <script type="text/javascript">
        window.baseUrl = '@Url.Content("~/")';  
   </script>
   @*<script type="text/javascript" src="@Url.Content("~/scripts/people.js")">    </script>*@
  </head>
```

in the people.js file, i am trying to call this function like this:

```
self.followersUrl = window.baseUrl("/People/Followers?uid=" + data.UserId);
```

but it is giving me error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: window.baseUrl is not a function
```

i want to know how to inject this.
On view page, i want to send this followersUrl and other url like this:

```
 <a data-bind="attr: { href: followersUrl }">
  <a class="btn pull-right" data-bind="visible: !isFollowed && !isOwnProfile, attr: { href: followAction }">Follow</a>
```

From the answer by Scott, he suggested this as window.baseUrl is not a function, so i tried this:

```
 self.followAction = window.baseUrl + '/People/Follow?uid=' + data.UserId;
```

now, when i tried clicking Follow button,

its giving error i checked this in console: **people/Follow?uid=8 net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED url in console is people/Follow?uid=8:1 but i am seeing correct url in browser tab which is people/Follow?uid=8**

here, as u can see capital P is changed to small p then i go back to .js file and tried this:

```
 self.followAction = window.baseUrl + 'localhost:44305/People/Follow?uid=' + data.UserId;
```

then its sending url like this:

```
 https://localhost:44305/localhost:44305/People/Follow?uid=8
```

what is happening here. please suggest me something

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tried everything given on internet but could not get it done then i tried manually inserting data to it and finally i wrote this line:

```
self.followAction = location.protocol + "//" + location.host + '/People/Follow?uid=' + data.UserId;
```

here, i dont need any external javascript function nor to call it from anywhere and it does the magic.

Answer (score 0):

`window.baseUrl` is a string, not a function.

You likely want:

```
window.baseUrl + '/People/Followers?uid=' + data.UserId;
```

Comment: thnk u i tried this its giving error i checked this in console: https://people/Follow?uid=8 net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED url in console is https://people/Follow?uid=8:1 but i am seeing correct url in browser tab which is https://people/Follow?uid=8

Comment: @duke Actually (deleted my other comment), if you're seeing the correct URL but the name isn't resolving, it looks like a different problem.  Maybe your ASP.NET application is running on a different port, which isn't being included in `Url.Content("~/");`?

Comment: can u suggest me something when i first load page then url is: https://localhost:44305/People/Index and when i click on one of the follow button its changes to https://people/Follow?uid=8 i have included in last line in question the button with href attribute @Scott Kaye

Comment: Looks like `window.baseUrl` either really is undefined (or null), because even if the URL was wrong, it wouldn't say the name wasn't resolved.  Did you copy my code exactly as the value of `self.followersUrl`?  The lowercase `p` and `Follow/Followers` indicate otherwise.

Comment: self.followAction = window.baseUrl +'/People/Follow?uid=' + data.UserId; then on view page <a class="btn pull-right" data-bind="visible: !isFollowed && !isOwnProfile, attr: { href: followAction }">Follow</a> this is the button which i am clicking i am also amazed

Comment: @duke Wow, I'm sorry to say that I have no idea what could be causing that then. It's super late where I am, but I'll see if I can look into it more in the morning if you don't get an answer by then.   Good luck!

Comment: thnk u scott for just giving me hint that there was problem with host or port number that clue led me to answer